# node:menu tokens not working in Pathauto

Tags: tokens, path-aliases

I can't get any node:menu-based tokens to work in my Pathauto replacement patterns.  Other tokens, such as *[current-user:name]* or *[node:language]*, work fine.  But the token I am trying to use, a menu-based token, specifically *[node:menu-link:parents:join:/]* does not. I've tried a slew of the node:menu-link tokens, such as *[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]*, and they're all being skipped.

When I bulk delete all Content aliases, then bulk update them, I do not get any error messages.  The resulting aliases from my pattern *[node:menu-link:parents:join:/]/[node:title]* just ends up being the node title. 
git status

I've been banging my head against this for days, and in trying to fix it have:

- installed [Token Tweaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) and set the depth to 2
- run drush *@test ev "token_clear_cache();* incessantly
- disabled [Menu Firstchild](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_firstchild), then when that didn't help...
- updated Menu Firstchild to the dev version and applied this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295059)
- applied this Token [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2238191)
- applied this core (!) [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/849624)

Now I'm running:

- Pathauto 7.x-1.2+21-dev
- Token 7.x-1.5+4-dev
- Token Tweaks 7.x-1.x-dev
- Menu Firstchild  7.x-1.1+1-dev

An additional detail:
Going to node/[nid]/devel/token for any given page hangs for a while, then displays a blank screen.  It produces three errors like this:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_studio_location in addressfield_tokens() (line 219 of /var/www/html/test/sites/all/modules/contrib/addressfield/addressfield.tokens.inc).
```

This doesn't seem particularly serious, but maybe relevant.

Any ideas? Even pointers on how to debug would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this was actually caused by the menu not being selected in the Menu Settings of this particular content type. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered that, after a full debug, it seems that `menu_tokens()` is not called at all.

```
  // There is a huge bug with menu tokens not being detected, to fix that, load
  // token include file and force repicking the menu_tokens() function as
  // implementation of hook_tokens()
  module_load_include('inc', 'token', 'token.tokens');
  module_implements('tokens', FALSE, TRUE);
```

That crappy hack fixed my problem but Why... just WHY ?

So yeah, after a deeper investigation, in `module_implements()`:

```
  $include_file = isset($hook_info[$hook]['group']) && module_load_include('inc', $module, $module . '.' . $hook_info[$hook]['group']);
  // Since module_hook() may needlessly try to load the include file again,
  // function_exists() is used directly here.
  if (function_exists($module . '_' . $hook)) {
    $implementations[$hook][$module] = $include_file ? $hook_info[$hook]['group'] : FALSE;
  }
```

Okay, so the only thing that is preventing menu from being picked is the sorting:

- if menu is processed before token in this `module_implements()`, the `menu.tokens.inc` include file will not be picked as it doesn't exist
- if token is before menu, the `token.tokens.inc` thus `menu_tokens()` function will be discovered and picked up after

<strike>So if you don't want any code, just alter the weight of token and menu so that menu's is higher than token's.</strike>

**But NO**, there is a `token_module_implements_alter()` that just does that, but it is not called, and that is the thing I couldn't figure out. So the final hack was:

```
  // Rebuild implementation cache
  cache_set('module_implements', array(), 'cache_bootstrap');
  cache_clear_all('hook_info', 'cache_bootstrap');
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome & thorough debugging — I'll have time to implement/test next week.